# How do I run 2 operations at a same click

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 functions 1. For Shifting columns in next sheet. 2. Convert them in lower case. I want to run this both at a same time on clicking. So i put them in same Sub(Sub Shift_LCase()) but this not not working only shifting is done but the data is not able to convert.

```
Sub Shift_LCase()

 Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    s1.Range("U:U").copy s2.Range("A1")
    s2.Range("U:U").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

    s1.Range("AR:AR").copy s2.Range("B1")
    s2.Range("AR:AR").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

    s1.Range("BF:BF").copy s2.Range("C1")
    s2.Range("BF:BF").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo


       Dim x As Range
       Dim rsheet As Worksheet
       Set rsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2)
   ' Loop to cycle through each cell in the specified range.
   For Each x In Range("A1:A4000")
      x.Value = LCase(x.Value)
   Next

   For Each x In Range("B1:B4000")
      x.Value = LCase(x.Value)
   Next

   For Each x In Range("C1:C4000")
      x.Value = LCase(x.Value)
   Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you copy stuff from column U of "Sheet1" to column A of "Sheet2" and then remove duplicates from column U of "Sheet2".  Was that column populated prior to running the macro, or is that a typo?

Comment: You have unqualified `Range` references (i.e. ones which do not include which sheet they refer to, such as `Range("U1:U4000")`).  Those references will default to the **active** worksheet.  Are you sure you don't want to use, for instance, `rsheet.Range("U1:U4000")`?  (You are using qualified references in the first half of the code, so it seems like you know what qualifying references is about, so I'm unsure of whether that is deliberate or not.)

Comment: @YowE3K I am not able to understand what u said above

Comment: Which comment don't you understand - my first one or my second one?

Comment: Second one. Is there any way to change the code

Comment: My **guess** (and only you can know for sure) is that you want the second half of that code to be referring to ranges on the worksheet you are referring to as `rsheet`.  (I'm guessing that because you created the reference to the worksheet but never use it.)  So my **guess** is that you want to use `rsheet.Range("U1:U4000")`, etc.

Comment: @YowE3K Firstly I want to shift my data from sheet1 to sheet2 so i used that range. Secondly I want to convert that into Lcase form

Comment: @YowE3K thanks for mentioning the range. I just changed the range and its working